# pdflatex: pdf not inserting properly when page sizes are different

Tags: pdftex

I have to insert pdfpages of differnt sizes(heights) whose page sizes i know. I am trying

```
\batchmode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=432pt \pdfpageheight=506.52pt
\includepdfmerge[]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=432pt \pdfpageheight=116.27999999999997pt
\includepdfmerge[]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 2}
\end{document}
```

What i am getting is

[image]

instead of

[image]

Comment: why don't you use the `fitpaper` option of pdfpages?

Comment: Where can i see the documentation for the options of `includepdfmerge`

Comment: Also i want to add page numbers. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/555470/how-to-add-page-number-for-a-pdf-file-whose-page-sizes-are-different

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi Does the desired page numbers enlarge the page size, or it just resides in the lower center of inserted page?

Comment: Using fitpaper does not respect the `\eject \pdfpagewidth=500pt \pdfpageheight=500pt` It changes the size of the paper. I am expecting `fitpaper` to fit into the 500pt x 500pt page size and also align it in the top left corner