# How to add page number for a pdf file whose page sizes are different

Tags: pdftex

I want to add page numbers at the bottom of each page in a pdf page. The page sizes are different

I left 15pt at the bottom of each page.

The following is my pdf how it looks

[image]

I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[footskip = 14mm,showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\cfoot{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont \thepage}

\begin{document}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=432pt \pdfpageheight=179.64pt
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1743}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=432pt \pdfpageheight=71.63999999999999pt
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1744}
\eject \pdfpagewidth=432pt \pdfpageheight=192.12pt
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1745}
\end{document}
```

What I get is

[image]

How to add page number at the bottom when page sizes are different

If all page sizes are same size then the following code works
Here my entire document is 432pt, 226pt (W,H). Using footskip=14mm, i can position the pagenumber preciselt where i want.

```
\batchmode
\documentclass[a4paper,]{article}
\usepackage[
    papersize={432pt, 226pt},
    footskip = 14mm,
    ]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{} 
\cfoot{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont \thepage}
\begin{document}
\the\textwidth; \the\textheight
\includepdfmerge[pagecommand={\thispagestyle{fancy}}]{/var/tmp/pdfjam-7FXkbO/source-1.pdf,-}
\end{document}
```

What i get is as below

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle i could do it by the following.

The answer is based on [Change Page Size Mid-Document: Fancy Header and Footer Horizontal Width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/250993/change-page-size-mid-document-fancy-header-and-footer-horizontal-width)

But still i have to struggle a lot and finally using `left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm` in `\newgeometry` did the job

Also `showframe` helper me to visualize the textarea.

The problem is fancyhdr does not adopt to the mid document page size changes. and then understading the geometry package was the key

But still i am half knowledge. and left few questions i have as comments in the script. I dont know what is their purpose. but trail and error i understood they are required.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} % THIS IS REQUIRED
% QUESTION:
% \documentclass{article} pushes the pagenumber down
% I dont know the reason
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} % THIS IS REQUIRED
% QUESTION:
% without the above line the page number is pushed down /out of the page
% I dont know the reason
% \usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{layoutwidth  = 432pt,
layoutheight = 179.64pt,
left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1743}

\newgeometry{layoutwidth  = 432pt,
layoutheight = 71.63999999999999pt,
left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1744}

\newgeometry{layoutwidth  = 432pt,
layoutheight = 192.12pt,
left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1745}
\end{document}
```

The output is

[image]

Also for how to add space at bottom (eg 15mm for page number) in a pdf with different page sizes  and then add pagenumber,  refer answer
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/556945/221200

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer? I think it's a lot easier than setting up a new pagelayout for each page.

Comment: I will check it. recently i started using tikz. When i asked this question i did know anything much

Answer (score 2):

My basic idea would be to wrap a `tikzpicture` in the `pagecommand` of the `\includepdfmerge`. In addition you would need the `remember picture, overlay` argument to write on the pdf and the `pagenodes` function of tikz to get the position at the bottom of your current page. This mechanism should be able to handle different page sizes of your included pdfs and put the pagenumber always at the bottom (set the `yshift` argument to a value that suits you).

MWE based on your code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages, tikz}

\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,pagecommand={
   \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
     \node[yshift=15pt] at (current page.south) {\thepage};
   \end{tikzpicture}}]{/var/tmp/pdfjam-7FXkbO/source-1.pdf,-}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have tried this. But the page size is constant.It kept the entire document the same page size as first page in the pdf

Comment: what is `\thepage` here. I am new to this.

Comment: \thepage prints the current page number

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [`incgraph`](https://ctan.org/pkg/incgraph) solution:

- in the first example, the page number is put inside the picture,
- in the second example, the page number is put outside the picture, hence enlarged the page size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{incgraph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\igrset{
  my page number/.style={
    overlay={
      \node[anchor=south] at ([yshift=5pt]page.south) {\thepage};
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
content
\incgraph[my page number][page=1]{example-image-a}

\igrpage{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (pic) {\includegraphics{example-image-b}};
    \node at ([yshift=-10pt]pic.south) {\thepage};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: first example]
[image: second example]