# How to add a extra space in the bottom of each page of a pdf

Tags: pdftex

I have a pdf file and want to add 15pt space at the bottom for each page. The pages are of different size

I am trying the following to show the pages.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1743}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1744}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 1745}
\end{document}
```

Now how can i add 15pt at the bottom of each in my above code.

The above code will create the following pdf

[image]

What is want is add 15pt space at the bottom like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following added extra space in the bottom of pdf page in the mid of the document with custom page size

I have a pdfpage of size `432pt x 240pt` I want to add at the bottom 15pt. SO the page size will be `432pt x 255pt`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
% offset is 7.5pt since the pdf will be centered initially
% templatesize is the most important part here. without templatesize fitpaper will create page size of 432x240
\includepdfmerge[offset=0 7.5,fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{255pt}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 497}
\end{document}
```

So 2 things in includepdfmerge to be done

a) `fitpaper, templatesize={432pt}{255pt}` (both have to be used together)

b) `offset=0 7.5` (since the page is centered after fitpage, we have to push it up `15/2`

The output looks like this

[image]

If we want to add page numbers then we can use the below

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} % required for page number
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage} % required for page numbergin
\begin{document
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 253.56pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
\includepdfmerge[offset=0 7.5,fitpaper,templatesize={432pt}{255pt},pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}]{/home/simha/latex/test.pdf, 497}
\end{document}
```

We will use

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[automark,headsepline,footsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

with

```
pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}
```

But for the above to work we have to add the below

```
\newgeometry{layoutwidth = 432pt,layoutheight = 255pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,top=0mm, bottom=0mm,footskip=1mm}
```

Then the output will look like (with both extra space and page numbering)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the trim option:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdfmerge[fitpaper,trim=0pt -1cm 0pt 0pt]{example-image-duck,1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: eg: I have a pdf page : 432pt (w) x 1000pt(ht) - I  want to trim first to 432pt (w) x 500pt(ht) - and now add 15pt empty space below. How can i do it then

Comment: also how to change color of the extra space